# Why by language spec, C# extension methods cannot make a type 'foreachable'?

Tags: c#, vb.net

When using a type as collection in a `foreach` clause, the type needs to have a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an object that has a `MoveNext` function with Boolean result and a `Current` property.  Usually this is realized by implementing IEnumerable.   However that is not required.

In C#, `GetEnumerator` should be defined on the collection type itself.

In Vb.Net, retrofitting `GetEnumerator`  by using extension methods is allowed.

Why not in C#?

Found by retrofitting .NET tuple classes in Vb. Net first and translate to C# later.

Sample code: https://github.com/nicenemo/Noaber?files=1

Comment: The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> interface. [from the msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx).

Comment: C# is not as forgiving, or as fast-moving, as VB - but I can see why this might not be allowed by-design because extension methods are a purely syntactic thing and might introduce unintended consequences if implemented as you propose (e.g. it breaks if the type later really does add `GetEnumerator`. If you really want to add `foreach` support then use a decorator pattern.

Comment: No, `MoveNext` and `Current` aren't defined on the collection type - they're defined on the type implementing `IEnumerator<T>`. The collection must have a `GetEnumerator()` method.

Comment: As always, it is because the Language Specification says so.  C# only does a member lookup for Current and MoveNext.  Typical for the C# team, they don't like the idea of changes in one file to cause hard-to-diagnose breakage in another.  VB.NET has a "make it work if you can" philosophy.

Comment: Indeed  implement GetEnumerator  that implement Current and MoveNext.  (wrote the code a year ago)  Also was afraid it is off topic.  So where to ask?

Comment: @Hans If you want to know why MS designed the language this way you need to *ask them*, rather than asking us to guess why they designed the language this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does foreach fail to find my GetEnumerator extension method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168143/why-does-foreach-fail-to-find-my-getenumerator-extension-method)

Comment: @Mark Close.  In Vb. Net it would work. Only Vb. Net has no var statement.  Type inference can be turned on/off per file with Option clause at the top of the file.

Comment: @Mark Good find, and it means my guess is off (even the bits that *could* be extension methods mustn't be), so I've deleted my answer.

Comment: The question presupposes that language designers need a reason to not do work. This presupposition is false, and therefore the question cannot be answered in its present form. Designers are not required to justify the absence of a feature. Rather, features must be justified by a compelling usage scenario in which the benefit of the feature can be seen to outweigh its costs. Note that opportunity costs are costs.

Comment: @EricLippert  How should I reformulated the question in such a way that the answer is not 42? My original thought was If I can 'foreach ',  I get LINQ for free.

Comment: @Hans - you should write a question that clearly outlines what work you're trying to accomplish - i.e. it sounds like "make X support LINQ" - rather than ask a question about why the language doesn't contain the feature that you think would help you solve the problem.

Comment: @Hans: The problem with a "why not?" question is that no answer is satisfying. "Because the spec says so" is not satisfying. "Because the language designers considered it and rejected it" is unsatisfying. StackOverflow is for questions that have *practical* answers. Ask yourself "what am I going to do differently based on the answer I get to my question?"  If you're not going to do anything different, then it's not a great question; the answer should motivate an action.  So: what question do you really need answered to do a better job of writing software?

Comment: I think the question should be something along the lines of rules for library writing. Rules that take into account C#, VB. NET and perhaps even F#. Besides that I am just curious why  the language designers do not support it in C#.

Comment: @Hans -no, again, if you want to ask a question here, it should be about the *practical* problem you're trying to solve - rather than to ask why certain languages don't contain certain features that (you imagine) would help you to solve them.

Comment: @Hans: Again, you are thinking about this the wrong way. It's like asking "why don't you bicycle to work?", "why don't you eat soup for lunch?", "why don't you live in France?" -- I could ask "why don't you?" questions all day, and most people would get pretty irritated pretty quickly. If I think it's a good idea for you to live in France, **I** am the one who has to convince you that it's not only a good idea, but it is **better** than every other place you could live.

Comment: @Hans: The language designers don't have to provide you a reason why they chose to not have that feature in C#. Rather, if you think it is an awesome feature then **convince the designers that it is better than every other feature that has been suggested but not implemented so far**, and it will get done. You want a reason why it isn't done? **Because you haven't convinced the design team to do it yet**.  If you want it done, **start convincing people**.

Comment: @Hans: "You haven't convinced them yet" is probably a deeply unsatisfying answer. You probably see now what I mean about every answer to a "why not" question being unsatisfying. My advice is: stop asking "why not" questions and instead ask "how" and "what" questions.

Comment: Since the compiler source is open nowadays I can try to make it work first before bothering anyone with 'why not? '.

Comment: Asked as feature request on Roslyn.  https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/242.  Made mental note to self to never ask Why or Why not on Stackoverflow.